# TSQL Trigger on Subscriber Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, triggers, rollback

I have a replicated subscriber table on SQL Server 2008. I have put a trigger on it that may or may not fail. The table is read only.

My question is :

If I use the following

```
SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint1
BEGIN TRY
...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepoint1
END CATCH
```

to rollback the transaction if there is some error in my trigger (in the ... part), will SQL Server attempt to update or rollback the read only subscriber table still causing an error?

Thanks.

Comment: What testing have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting the trigger on the publisher where it will work?  And you don't want it to work on the subscriber but you don't know how to disable it?

If that's true, you might try the NOT FOR REPLICATION tag on the trigger:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176072.aspx